# Class validator with numbers and enum

Tags: validation, nestjs, dto

I want to create a DTO in nestjs using class-validator.

The value can accept a value between 1-24,trial or lifetime

I created an enum like this

```
export enum PeriodEnum {
    "trial" = "trial",
    "lifetime" = "lifetime"
}
```

And I tried to used this validation

```
@IsNotEmpty()            
@ApiProperty(CustomersConfigSwagger.API_PROP_REF_PERIOD)
@Min(0)
@Max(24)
@IsEnum(Object.keys(PeriodEnum))
period: string;
```

I get an error if I pass 1:

```
   "period must be a valid enum value",
    "period must not be greater than 10",
    "period must not be less than 0"
```

I tried to add

```
"1" = "1"
```

But the "An enum member cannot have a numeric"

I tried even with RegExp

```
@IsNotEmpty()            
@ApiProperty(CustomersConfigSwagger.API_PROP_REF_PERIOD)
@Matches(`/^(${Object.keys(PeriodEnum)}|[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-4])$/`) 
period: string;
```

Answer (score 0):

since you are accepting `strings`, `@Min` and `@Max` no longer make sens. so here you need to deal with your numbers as `string`.

what I suggest is to create your own `validation decorator` :

```js
export function IsLifetimeOrTrialOrBetween1and24(
  validationOptions?: ValidationOptions
) {
  return function (object: Object, propertyName: string) {
    registerDecorator({
      name: "IsLifetimeOrTrialOrBetween1and24",
      target: object.constructor,
      propertyName: propertyName,
      options: validationOptions,
      validator: {
        validate(value: any) {
          // you manage your logic here then return either TRUE or FALSE
        },
      },
    });
  };
}
```

then use it like this :

```js
@IsLifetimeOrTrialOrBetween1and24({
   message: 'should be lifetime trial or a number between 1 and 24',
})
readonly period: string;
```

learn more [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/class-validator#table-of-contents)

but if you don't want to custom validation decorator this is an ugly solution but it works fine :

```js
@IsIn(['trial', 'lifetime', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7',...,'23','24'])
readonly period: string;
```

Answer (score 0):

I edited my DTO like this:

```js
@IsNotEmpty()            
@ApiProperty(CustomersConfigSwagger.API_PROP_REF_PERIOD)
@Matches(`^(${Object.values(PeriodEnum).join("|")}|[1-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4])$`)

period: string;
```

It works as I want now

Answer (score 0):

`@Min()` decorator can't check cause by the data type of `period` is `string`.
Please cast `period` to number to valid Min and Max.
In your case, I use `@Type()` decorator to cast:

```
@IsNotEmpty()            
@ApiProperty(CustomersConfigSwagger.API_PROP_REF_PERIOD)
@Type(() => Number)
@Min(0)
@Max(24)
@IsEnum(Object.keys(PeriodEnum))
period: string;
```